# Cassandra CPU Load (too much)

Tags: cassandra, bigdata, cql, cassandra-2.0

Using `top`

```
8260 root      20   0 5163m 4.7g **133m** S 144.6 30.5   2496:46 java
```

Most of the time %CPU is >170.

I am trying to identify the issue. I think GC or flushing is too blame.

```
 S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT    LGCC                 GCC 
0.00  16.73  74.74  29.33  59.91  27819  407.186   206   10.729  417.914 Allocation Failure   No GC     
0.00  16.73  99.57  29.33  59.91  27820  407.186   206   10.729  417.914 Allocation Failure   Allocation Failure
```

Also from Cassandra logs, it says Replaying position with the same segment ID and memtable is flushing too often.

```
INFO  [SlabPoolCleaner] 2015-01-20 13:55:48,515 ColumnFamilyStore.java:840 - Enqueuing flush of bid_list: 112838010 (11%) on-heap, 0 (0%) off-heap
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:1587] 2015-01-20 13:55:48,516 Memtable.java:325 - Writing Memtable-bid_list@2003093066(23761503 serialized bytes, 211002 ops, 11%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:1587] 2015-01-20 13:55:49,251 Memtable.java:364 - Completed flushing /root/Cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.1.2/bin/./../data/data/bigdspace/bid_list-27b59f109fa211e498559b0947587867/bigdspace-bid_list-ka-3965-Data.db (4144688 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1421647511710, position=25289038)
INFO  [SlabPoolCleaner] 2015-01-20 13:56:23,429 ColumnFamilyStore.java:840 - Enqueuing flush of bid_list: 104056985 (10%) on-heap, 0 (0%) off-heap
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:1589] 2015-01-20 13:56:23,429 Memtable.java:325 - Writing Memtable-bid_list@1124683519(21909522 serialized bytes, 194778 ops, 10%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:1589] 2015-01-20 13:56:24,130 Memtable.java:364 - Completed flushing /root/Cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.1.2/bin/./../data/data/bigdspace/bid_list-27b59f109fa211e498559b0947587867/bigdspace-bid_list-ka-3967-Data.db (3830733 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1421647511710, position=25350445)
INFO  [SlabPoolCleaner] 2015-01-20 13:56:55,493 ColumnFamilyStore.java:840 - Enqueuing flush of bid_list: 95807739 (9%) on-heap, 0 (0%) off-heap
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:1590] 2015-01-20 13:56:55,494 Memtable.java:325 - Writing Memtable-bid_list@473510037(20170635 serialized bytes, 179514 ops, 9%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:1590] 2015-01-20 13:56:56,151 Memtable.java:364 - Completed flushing /root/Cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.1.2/bin/./../data/data/bigdspace/bid_list-27b59f109fa211e498559b0947587867/bigdspace-bid_list-ka-3968-Data.db (3531752 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1421647511710, position=25373052)
```

Any help or suggestion would be great. I have also disabled durable write false for the KeySpace. Thanks

Just found out after restarting all the nodes, YGC on one of the server is kicking in even if nothing is happening. Stopped the dumping of data etc.

Comment: Your path contains apache-cassandra-2.1.2, why is this tagged Cassandra-2.0?

Comment: I think the way sstables and internal structure is considered. Cassandra 2.0 and 2.1+ are quite similar. Not a major overhaul. Also there was no tag for 2.1.2. This is a general issue which can occur even using Cassandra 2.0

Answer (score 1):

What type of compaction do you use? Size tiered or Leveled?
If you are using leveled compaction, can you switch off over to Size tiered as you seem to have too many compactions. Increasing the sstable size for leveled compaction may also help.

> **sstable_size_in_mb** (Default: 160MB)
>    The target size for SSTables that use the leveled compaction strategy. Although SSTable sizes
>   should be less or equal to sstable_size_in_mb, it is possible to have
>   a larger SSTable during compaction. This occurs when data for a given
>   partition key is exceptionally large. The data is not split into two
>   SSTables.

(http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/reference/referenceTableAttributes.html#reference_ds_zyq_zmz_1k__sstable_size_in_mb)

If you are using size tiered compaction, increase the number of SS Tables before you see a minor compaction. This is set when the table is created, so you can change it using ALTER command. Example below:

> ALTER TABLE users   WITH
>   compaction_strategy_class='SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'   AND
>   min_compaction_threshold = 6;

Compact after 6 SSTables are created

Comment: I use Leveled compaction ( because I need fast reads ). I am using ActiveMQ so data goes into the queue first then its get written to Cassandra. So writing is not an issue. Is there any guide to what should be the size f the sstable ? also If the problem is not resolved by this and I change to size tiered compaction where to increase the number of SS tables before I see the compaction.? thanks a lot

Comment: Leveled compaction causes compaction and high disk usage, if you Level 0 SS Table is filling up fast. I would either recommend you guys to use size tiered compaction or use leveled compaction with higher size for Level 0.

Comment: Added information on how you can increase the size of leveled or increase the number of SSTables for size tiered. Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will do the changing at 2pm ( thats when the traffic is low ) and my ActiveMQ can easily hold the traffic when I am making changes in Cassandra. Will post the results the next morning. I am also looking into data tier compaction, its looks promising according to the type of work I am doing.

Comment: After increasing the sstable_size_in_mb , still the cpu load is too high and compaction is always happening on one of the node (that is being used for analytics) on the rest of the 2 nodes the CPU load is down to 50% (thats good). How much can I increase the size. When compaction to occur finally its going to put a load of stress on the cpu ? right  iostats show %util never go above 75 and mostly remain less the 40 so disk cant be blamed. Should I totally revert to some other compaction strategy ?

Comment: ./nodetool compactionstats;
pending tasks: 61

Comment: The load does goes down when compaction stops :). But still I need a permanent solution.

Comment: Somehow your datamodel seems to be inducing lot of compactions. You can go ahead and increase the SSTable size, but in general leveled compactions will cause high cpu /disk load compared to size tiered compactions

Comment: If you are ok with sacrificing the read latency a little bit, size tiered with 32 SS Tables should reduce the number of compactions. Major compaction should also be disabled(it is by default)

Comment: I will look into all these strategies. I am really grateful for your help. I have one more question. I am using TTL of 3 days with all my date.  So all replicas will hit TTL at the same time. So what should be my gc_grace period. I think setting it to zero would be a good solution to keep the disk space to a minimum. ?

Comment: gc_grace_seconds is by default 10 days, do you really want to keep it to 0? You can keep it 3 days just to take care of distributed deletes

Comment: What I can understand. gc_grace_period is the time after which the tombstones will be deleted. As TTL on all the replicas will hit at the same time so gc_grace =0 would be better as all the data would be deleted. As TTL > gc_grace so no tombstones would be created. Setting it to 3 days will have a similar effect. Am I right ? I am making a few changing to support data tier compaction. Its looks promising according to the data I have.

Comment: gc_grace of 0 should be fine, for your use case scenario